# Why is voice chat in Dungeons and Dragons Online usually not working?

Tags: voice-chat, dungeons-and-dragons-online

I rather suspect it's my ISP filtering it but I haven't figured out a way to prove this and they categorically deny filtering.

It's random, occasionally it suddenly starts working for a while, anywhere from seconds to hours, but it never lasts.  This started early this year when the Pirate Cove special showed up--at first it failed only in the wilderness part of it but soon it was at least 95% of the time everywhere in the game.

Turbine's tech support suggested the filtering bit as a possibility after exhausting configuration ideas, my ISP lied about it (I know they do traffic shaping) and I'm stumped.

Note that when people talk my screen does show that they are talking, I just don't hear anything.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tested to see if this happens on other systems for you?  Say a desktop and a laptop connected to the same ISP connection at home.  Most often when I have guild-mates or party members complain about audio issues it is due to their personal user settings.  Make sure that voice-chat is turned on even if you have no microphone, if you use a headset sometimes, and speakers other times, especially if the headset is USB or wireless, you will have to go in to your audio configurations and confirm that the game is looking for the correct device.  If these suggestions do not easily help you, please let me know, I'll work up an audio configuration tutorial page on DDOwiki to help you. (I should make one anyways, but this may bump up it's priority ;-))

Comment: It's not settings--the problem is intermittent, although it has become very unusual by now for it to not end up blocked.  Strangely enough I recently had an incident where *OUTGOING* talk worked (and I wasn't even trying to chat, the mute on my mic failed!)